# How to initiate a listener dependent on an async call in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase with React. On auth change (including first load) user data is loaded.

```
fetchUser: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      unsub();
      resolve(user);
    }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
}),
```

Some menus depend on users role and the user can switch roles.

```
firebaseDb.ref("settings").child(uid).child("role").on('value', snap =>{
    this.setState({role: snap.val()});
});
```

I get my users data only in `render` method (in `componentDidMount` `user` is `undefined` ) where I can not initiate any function calls as that would trigger an infinite loop (`render` is called multiple times by React). I also can not add role call to user's call data call because it does not change authentication i.e. does not trigger `onAuthStateChanged` thus UI elements that need to change don't as the user is switching roles.

How do I initiate this role listener dependent on an async call?